# Допустимо ли двоеточие перед "это"?

Tags: пунктуация

География поставок на данный момент очень обширна и продолжает постоянно расти: это практически вся Сибирь, многие регионы России и даже страны СНГ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

География поставок на данный момент очень обширна и продолжает постоянно расти - это практически вся Сибирь, многие регионы России и даже страны СНГ.

Лучше поставить тире и считать, что это пояснение в добавочном сообщении (без предупреждающей о пояснении паузы). Двоеточие перед "это" смотрится не лучшим образом.

Answer (score 2):

Двоеточие смотрится очень хорошо и вполне объяснимо. Вторая часть поясняет первую, раскрывая её содержание.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что нужно тире, по аналогии с присоединительным предложением в БСП. Но не уверена, что здесь характер именно присоединительный. Здесь все же скорее пояснение.